# Creating JQL query on Jira that will pull tickets from multiple projects

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to create a JQL query that will pull tickets from 3 separate projects, with the same field.
So I wanna get all tickets that have the field month= 'May' from project1, project2, project3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the in clause

Something like this

[image]

Comment: Why would you post a screenshot? It's not even a real query in your system. Just copy&paste the text.